# Modifying localIdentName in css-loader doesn't work in webpack 5 react 17

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

Currently I am using webpack 5, react 17 and @dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules and all other latest packages.

I am excluding the sass/css files in **assets/stylesheets** which is being treated as global and using those classes inside **className**

Styles won't be applied changing **localIdentName** to something else. Tried **getLocalIdent** but no use.

[Github Repo Link](https://github.com/sharathm89/react-app)

So how to change the localIdentName ?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Template App",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^6.0.10",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-scss": "^3.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

console.log(`Environment: ${isDev ? "development" : "production"}`);

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  mode: isDev ? "development" : "production",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: false,
    stats: "errors-warnings",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss|less)$/,
        use: [
          isDev ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                auto: (resourcePath) =>
                  resourcePath.indexOf("assets/stylesheets") === -1,
                  localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                  // getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
                  //   return "whatever_random_class_name";
                  // },
              },
              sourceMap: isDev,
            },
          },
          "sass-loader"
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    })
  ],
  devtool: isDev ? "source-map" : false,
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules",
      {
        "webpackHotModuleReloading": true,
        "autoResolveMultipleImports": true,
        "filetypes": {
          ".scss": {
            "syntax": "postcss-scss"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? Looks like I have answered for you this question

Comment: @tmhao2005  yes the other issue was solved but now not able to change localIdentName to something else..   like for ex instead of this `[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]` i need to change it to `[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]`

Comment: @tmhao2005 basically it should have been like `isDev ? localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]" : [hash:base64:5]"` for development and production.   But doesn't seem to work as per the above config file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like I forgot to tell you `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` has an option to configure the scoped name too which is called `generateScopedName`.

As long as you configured this as same as `css-loader`, it should work then:

- `.babelrc`

```json
[
  "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules",
  {
    "generateScopedName": "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]", // switch to whatever you want to
    // ...
  }
]
```

- `webpack.config.js`:

```json
{
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
    modules: {
      // ...
      localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
    },
  },
},
```

NOTE: In case of generating based on env, you should use js babel config file `babel.config.js` so you can conditionally generate the name via `NODE_ENV`

Comment: thanks it wokred and depending upon env i was able to make it dynamic.

Comment: is it possible to check this issue having similar kind of issue related to loaders in storybook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65464491/module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-10-with-storybook-6-1-11-webpa

Comment: No problem. I’m checking as I’m free then :)