# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) with Storybook 6.1.11, Webpack 5.11.0, React 17.0.1

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, storybook, webpack-5

Trying to setup a react-app with all latest versions.

[Github Repo Link](https://github.com/sharathm89/react-app)

Trying to run storybook with sass file imported will result in below error. Trying to run without importing the styles, storybook works.

The same code works correctly when its run as `npm start run` with no warnings and errors.

I have configured css modules using **@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules** with sass, webpack 5, react 17 and with latest packages.

```
ERROR in ./src/assets/stylesheets/app.scss 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import "./base.scss";
| @import "./generics/font.scss";
| @import "./generics/spacing.scss";
 @ ./stories/index.js 5:0-44 8:2-10:4 8:58-10:3 9:4-49
 @ ./src/components/atoms/button/stories.js
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules",
      {
        webpackHotModuleReloading: true,
        autoResolveMultipleImports: true,
        filetypes: {
          ".scss": {
            syntax: "postcss-scss",
          },
        },
        generateScopedName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

**webpack.config.js** for css (partial code inlcuded)

```
{
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          isDev ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                auto: (resourcePath) =>
                  resourcePath.indexOf("assets/stylesheets") === -1,
                localIdentName:"[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
              },
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      }
```

**storybook/webpack.config.js** file

```
const custom = require('../webpack.config.js');

module.exports = {
  // stories: ['../src/components/**/*.stories.js'],
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      module: {
        rules: custom.module.rules,
      },
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        ...custom.resolve,
      }
    };
  },
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you have done with your configuration but you would define the config things inside `.storybook/main.js`. And for global style css is supposed to be included in `preview.js` file.

In short, you have to do the few things:

- Remove your `.storybook/config.js` and add `.storybook/main.js` with following content:

```js
const custom = require('../webpack.config.js');

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/stories.js', // The name should have a prefix for component name like `button.stories.js` instead of `stories.js` like you've done. As you renamed, you can remove this pattern
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      module: {
        rules: custom.module.rules,
      },
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        ...custom.resolve,
      }
    };
  },
};
```

- Create the `.storybook/preview.js` to import your global style:

```js
import "../src/assets/stylesheets/app.scss";
```

Comment: thanks it worked..  I added storybook using this command `npx sb init` mentioned in this link https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/install so above files were generated by it..   what is the reason to change those files

Comment: Here's the official document telling to custom `webpack` https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config. Your error was your configuration had no impact :) then I made it impact again

Answer (score 3):

Some people have been [running into problems](https://gist.github.com/shilman/8856ea1786dcd247139b47b270912324#gistcomment-3679539) a some scss preset when using Storybook 6.2.0 with Webpack 5. Instead of using a preset, I recommend configuring the Webpack config in main.js as mentioned above. Here's the relevant portion of a working Storybook Webpack config for Sass:

```
module: {
        ...config.module,
        rules: [
          ...config.module.rules,
          {
            test: /\.(scss)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader',
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
              },
              {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                  postcssOptions: {
                    plugins: function () {
                      return [require('precss'), require('autoprefixer')];
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                options: {
                  implementation: require('sass'),
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
```

I've written more about getting Storybook off the ground with Webpack 5 (and modifying the Storybook Webpack config) [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66825007/3577110).

Comment: if you have storybook added to nrwl workspace then this will work. All these loaders will already be installed if you have setup your react library to use scss style option from nrwl cli

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this might happen: if you are adding new components to your app and the path defined for your sass-loader does not match anymore.

E.g. if you have this in your `.storybook/main.js`:

```
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    // Add SASS support
    // https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#examples
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        "style-loader",
        {
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            modules: {
              compileType: "icss",
            },
          },
        },
        "sass-loader",
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    })
```

Update or completely remove the `include` path.